# scraping table without table class

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, scrape

im trying to scrape table from https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=IDR&MA=1&DD1=&MM1=08&YYYY1=1995&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=23&MM2=07&YYYY2=2020&btnOK=Go%21 but im not able to scrape data because i cant find the table class,can anyone help with the right indenfication? thank you in advance.

```
    import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=IDR&MA=1&DD1=&MM1=08&YYYY1=1995&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=23&MM2=07&YYYY2=2020&btnOK=Go%21"

    r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table', border = 1)
print(table)

    result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['month', 'average USD/idr=', 'Min USD/IDR=', 'Max USD/IDR=', 'Nb of working days'])

result.to_csv("usd_.csv", index=False)

df = pd.read_csv("usd_.csv")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html(
    "https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=IDR&MA=1&DD1=&MM1=08&YYYY1=1995&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=23&MM2=07&YYYY2=2020&btnOK=Go%21", header=0)[-3]

print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [check online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/4936949aa520d9bc7ddb683b4a84bde7/data.csv)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find an element by type and any attribute:

```
table = soup.find('table', {"border": "1"})
```